# When reading command line arguments in Windows script, is there a way to escape the comma character?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am trying to read multiple input parameters from the command-line. The last one is expected to be a comma-separated list, but the script is only able to read the first word before the comma.

That is, when I call the script: `test.cmd a b c d,e,f`
`%4` comes as `d`, whereas I want it to be read as `d,e,f`

I've looked up quite a few sources to figure this out, but it seems the command-line arguments in Windows cannot be manipulated (tokenized etc.) and are passed to the script as is. Is this true? Is there no way to escape the , while reading input from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote your arguments, then retrieve them with `%~1`, `%~2`, etc.  If you do `test.cmd a b c "d,e,f"`, `%~4` will contain `d,e,f`.

Edit: Here's the workaround I describe in the second comment below:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

echo 1: %~1
echo 2: %~2
echo 3: %~3

:loop
if not "%~4"=="" (
    if defined four ( set "four=%four%,%~4" ) else set "four=%~4"
    shift /4
    goto loop
)

echo 4: %four%
```

Example session:

[image: tokens]

Comment: Ooh yes, thanks! Is this not possible to do without altering how the user is expected to pass the arguments?

Comment: No.  Windows tokenizes arguments on whitespace, commas, semicolons, and I'm not sure what other characters.  `test.cmd a b c d,e,f` has 6 arguments.  You could join `%~4%~5%~6` together as a workaround I suppose.  If there are an unknown number of fields in the csv list or if it is likely to have more fields than can be read in as `%~1` through `%~9`, you'll probably have to loop and `shift`, appending a variable on each iteration until `%~4` is empty.  Easier just to expect the user to quote the argument, really.

Comment: Definitely, **quoting parameters** properly seems to be a **best practice** to achieve the OP's target under all circumstances!

Answer (score 1):

The method below allows you to separate any number of arguments grouped by commas:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get command line arguments
set "args=%*"
set n=0
for %%a in ("%args: =" "%") do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "arg[!n!]=%%~a"
)

echo Argument 4: %arg[4]%

rem Show all arguments given
echo/
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo %%i- !arg[%%i]!
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat a b c d,e,f o,p,q,r x,y,z
Argument 4: d,e,f

1- a
2- b
3- c
4- d,e,f
5- o,p,q,r
6- x,y,z
```